# Change a button label using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a submit button which I am sharing between 'Create' and 'Update'.  I want the following labels depending on my page state:

- Create = Submit
- Update = Update

These buttons also have an image at the front of them using `glyphicon` but the image will be the same for both buttons.

To get to my page states (listed above) I have other JavaScript functions which the relevant buttons call.

All my code is below. I am struggling as I am fairly new to JavaScript and I now I can do it by adding using `Value` but this doesn't work due to my image.

**Edit Button HTML**

```
<button type="button"class="btn btn-default" name="RegCashMove_Edit_Button" onclick='RegCashMoveEdit()'>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
</button>
```

**Create Button HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="RegCashMove_Create_Button" onclick='RegCashMoveCreate()'>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
</button>
```

**Variable Button HTML**

This is the button I want the label to be variable on. At the moment its 'Submit'

```
<button name="RegularCashMovements_Submit_Button" class="btn btn-default" id="RegularCashMovements_Submit_Button" type="submit">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit
</button>
```

**JavaScript function for 'Create' button**

```
function RegCashMoveCreate(txt) {
    document.getElementById('selection').value = "Create";
    document.getElementById('index').value = "";
    document.getElementById('RCMViewState').value = "Initial";

    document.getElementById('submitAndCancel').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('editAndConfirm').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('yesAndNo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('confirmTemplate').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('createEditDeleteTopLine').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveHeading').innerHTML = "<h3>" + txt + "</h3>";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveFields').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveDeleteConfirmation').style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById('FromDiv').innerHTML = "<%=fromInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('ToDiv').innerHTML = "<%=toInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('AmountDiv').innerHTML = "<%=amountInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('FrequencyDiv').innerHTML = "<%=frequencyInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('FromErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('ToErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('AmountErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('FrequencyErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";

    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_From_DropDownList').value = "- - Please select - -";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_To_DropDownList').value = "- - Please select - -";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_Amount_TextBox').value = "";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_Frequency_DropDownList').value = "0";
};
```

**JavaScript function for 'Edit' button**

```
function RegCashMoveEdit(txt, from, to, amount, frequency, index) {
    document.getElementById('selection').value = "Edit"
    document.getElementById('index').value = index;
    document.getElementById('RCMViewState').value = "Initial";

    document.getElementById('submitAndCancel').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('editAndConfirm').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('yesAndNo').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('confirmTemplate').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('createEditDeleteTopLine').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveHeading').innerHTML = "<h3>" + txt + "</h3>";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveFields').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('RegCashMoveDeleteConfirmation').style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById('FromDiv').innerHTML = "<%=fromInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('ToDiv').innerHTML = "<%=toInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('AmountDiv').innerHTML = "<%=amountInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('FrequencyDiv').innerHTML = "<%=frequencyInnerHtml%>";
    document.getElementById('FromErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('ToErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('AmountErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('FrequencyErrorDiv').innerHTML = "";

    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_From_DropDownList').value = from;
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_To_DropDownList').value = to;
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_Amount_TextBox').value = amount;
    document.getElementById('RegCashMove_Frequency_DropDownList').value = frequency;
};
```

I no I should be able to add a variable in each of my JavaScript function to display the relevant label but my issue is getting it on the button with my image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the textual content of a HTML element with the "textContent" property ("innerText" in IE < 9):

```
var button = document.getElementById('RegularCashMovements');
button.innerText = button.textContent = 'new text';
```

The span element inside the button element should not be removed.
If you also want to change the title of the span do it like that:

```
for (var index = 0; index < button.childNodes.length; index++) {
    if (button.childNodes[index].tagName == 'SPAN') {
        button.childNodes[index].title = 'new title';
        break;
    }
}
```

You need to iterate through all child nodes of the button, instead of taking the first one, because than you will get the text content of the button again.

I hope i understood your problem. I also have to say, that your javascript is very procedural and inperformant because of all the "display: none;" and innerHTML accesses. My tip for you would be to think more objective and put all elements you need to hide in one container element and hide that one.